# 'Error: Your connection isn't private' when applying ssl certificate to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cname

I get an error when applying ssl certificate to my API on AWS elastic beanstalk via Load-balancer,
when I start setting up the ssl certificate I enter a domain and I validate it via Email ( this domain doesn't relate to aws or my API on elastic beanstalk).
Now I get 'Your connection isn't private, NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID', so I can't open it in the browser without proceeding manually, I also can't connect my front-end(which runs over https) to it, I get the same error in console.
Help please
thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you actually did, but an HTTPS server certificate must identify, and be validated for, the domainname (or domainnames) you use to connect to the server(s). If you have a certificate for domain ABC and try to use it on a server for domain DEF, all clients will detect that the certificate is not for DEF and therefore the server is not a legitimate server for DEF and must be a fraudulent imposter fake. ...

Comment: ... Also, the 'common_name' terminology is out of date: X.509/PKIX certificates can use the SubjectAlternativeNames extension which supersedes the old CommonName attribute in Subject, and practically all certs from HTTPS CAs since about 2010 do so. So if you need to look at a cert and check it, look at SAN instead of (or before) CN.

Comment: so what do you suggest about the domain? yes the certificate in the domain isn't the same for the server I'm applying it on ( the API), what do you suggest about that?

Comment: Can I point a subdomain from the domain in the certificate for the server somehow ?

Comment: I suggest you make them the same. Either use a domainname that matches the cert, or get a cert that matches the domainname. I have no idea what 'point a subdomain' means, but if you mean can you use a cert for domainname example.com to authenticate abc.example.com, no you can't -- even though the owner of example.com normally will also own abc.example.com. But check your cert, specifically SAN: MANY CAs nowadays automatically issue certs for both example.com and www.example.com, because people so often want those two.

Answer (score 0):

I know it’s been a while since this question was posted. But for those who may be facing the issue now, as I was, I solved it by requesting a certificate for `*.mydomain.xyz`, instead of `mydomain.xyz`.

Comment: Better to have a clearer answer.